# Parsing output of textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a HTML form with a textarea in it.

When entering a text with some enters in it, my Javascript malformes and wont load.

The forms submits to a PHP script that outputs the javascript below.

How can I fix this?

```
function confirmsms() {
var redirect = confirm("Er zullen 791 smsjes worden verzonden, klik op OK om  door te gaan");
if (redirect == true) {
    window.location.href = 'send.phpregio=%&vakgebied=Loodgieter&disciplines=&bericht=aasdasd
asdasda
sdasdasd'; 
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Space after `?` and no concatenation on new lines.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistage in my layout in the post. There is no space present :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
function confirmsms() {
    var redirect = confirm("Er zullen 791 smsjes worden verzonden, klik op OK om  door te gaan");
    if (redirect == true) {
        window.location.href = 'send.php?'
        + 'regio=%&vakgebied=Loodgieter&disciplines=&'
        + 'bericht=aasdasdasdasdasdasdasd'; 
    }
}
```

UPDATE: It seems that your php variable `$b‌​ericht` has line returns in it.  Let's sanitize the variable to remove spaces and line returns like so:

`$bericht = str_replace(array(' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $bericht);`

Then you can use your code as before.  To be safe, I would sanitize all your php variables that are going to be dropped right into javascript.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function confirmsms() {
                var redirect = confirm(\"Er zullen $count smsjes worden verzonden, klik op OK om door te gaan\");
                if (redirect == true) {
                    window.location.href = 'send.php?regio=$regio&vakgebied=$vakgebied2&disciplines=$disciplines&bericht=$b‌​ericht';            }
             }
```

Comment: So how would I do that in PHP? My current code is like this:
`print "
<HTML><HEAD>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function confirmsms() {
   var redirect = confirm(\"Er zullen $count smsjes worden verzonden, klik op OK om door te gaan\");
   if (redirect == true) {
       window.location.href = 'send.php?regio=$regio&vakgebied=$vakgebied2&disciplines=$disciplines&bericht=$bericht'; 
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is you are not encoding your URL! As in your problem you are passing data using GET method your data will be the part of the URL itself!

Simply use [encodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) before sending! So your code should look like

```
function confirmsms() { var redirect = confirm("Er zullen 791 smsjes worden verzonden, klik op OK om  door te gaan"); var encodedValue = encodeURI("YOUR TEXTAREA VALUE HERE"); if (redirect == true) {     window.location.href = 'send.php?VAR1=VAL1&VAR2=VAL2'; }}
```

And at the back-end you can decode URL using [string urldecode ( string $str )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Hope you this is what you are looking for!